# Conflicting setter definitions for property "thenComparing":

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson

I'm getting the following exception when attempting to deserialize an object that uses a builder. I'm not sure what it's referring to by the thenComparing property. I will say that the builder is using the     `@JsonPOJOBuilder(withPrefix = "")` annotation.

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Conflicting setter definitions for property "thenComparing": java.util.Comparator#thenComparing(1 params) vs java.util.Comparator#thenComparing(1 params)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createAndCache2(DeserializerCache.java:266)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createAndCacheValueDeserializer(DeserializerCache.java:241)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache.findValueDeserializer(DeserializerCache.java:142)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.findRootValueDeserializer(DeserializationContext.java:394)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectReader._findRootDeserializer(ObjectReader.java:1379)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectReader._bindAndClose(ObjectReader.java:1264)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectReader.readValue(ObjectReader.java:896)
    at com.theexceptioncatcher.ProjectStocks.SharedLibrary.JSONDailyResultTest.deserialization(JSONDailyResultTest.java:47)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:160)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:74)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:211)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:67)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Conflicting setter definitions for property "thenComparing": java.util.Comparator#thenComparing(1 params) vs java.util.Comparator#thenComparing(1 params)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.POJOPropertyBuilder.getSetter(POJOPropertyBuilder.java:303)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerFactory.filterBeanProps(BeanDeserializerFactory.java:629)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerFactory.addBeanProps(BeanDeserializerFactory.java:527)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerFactory.buildBuilderBasedDeserializer(BeanDeserializerFactory.java:322)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerFactory.createBuilderBasedDeserializer(BeanDeserializerFactory.java:180)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createDeserializer(DeserializerCache.java:341)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createAndCache2(DeserializerCache.java:261)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with this is that the filter for the setters allowed for everything in. It turned out there were multiple definitions for "thenComparing" which caused this issue.